# Search results displaying all information in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to search some data from a database and display it. However whenever I click on 'search' all the results in the table are displayed. Any way I can display only the information the user is searching? 
This is the html code for the form.

```
<h2> Search </h2>
<form action = "search.php" method = "post" >
  Search for: <input type = "text" name ="find" placeholder="Animal Type/Date"><span   class="required"</span> in
  <select NAME = "field">
    <Option VALUE = "Animal Type"> Animal Type</option>
    <Option VALUE = "dateseen"> Date Required</option>

  </Select>
  <input type= "hidden" name = "searching" value ="yes"/>
  <input type= "submit" name = "search" value ="Search"/>
</form>
```

This is the PHP code I'm using.

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,"AnimalTracker1");

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysqli_error($link));
  }

//$find = strtoupper($find);
//$find = strip_tags($find);
//$find = trim($find);

$sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations  ");

if ($sql == FALSE)
{
  die($sql." Error on query: ".mysqli_error($link)); 
}

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo  $result ['Animal Type'];
echo "<br>";
echo $result ['Latitude'];
echo "<br> ";
echo $result ['Longitude'];
echo " <br>";
echo $result ['Seen'];
echo " <br> ";
echo $result ['Time'];
echo "<br> ";
echo "<br> ";
}
//}
?>
```

Comment: Its normal because your query does actually select all datas.

Comment: "Select * FROM Locations  " will select all the rows in table, in order to search use a query like "Select * FROM Locations WHERE Time=***** "

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to first grab the `find` field of your text box like this..

```
$searchKeyword = $_POST['find']; // Sanitize this value first !!
```

Next you need to pass it to your query... Change your `yourcolumn` to suit your column name.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations WHERE `yourcolumn` LIKE '%$searchKeyword%' ");
```

**`EDIT :`**

You could grab both fields and do a check..

```
if(!empty($_POST['find']) && !empty($_POST['field']))
    {
        //do your query like..
        $searchKeyword = $_POST['find']; // Sanitize this value first !!
        $searchKeyword2 = $_POST['field']; // Sanitize this value first !!

        $sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations WHERE `yourcolumn` LIKE '%$searchKeyword%' AND `yourcolumn2` LIKE '%$searchKeyword2%' ");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The search criteria cannot be empty !";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks byt I get this error when I do that.. 
Error on query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`%Dog%'' at line 1

Comment: Seems like i used a backtick before the search keyword. I have modified the answer can you try that ?

Comment: Thanks so much that did work!
If you dont mind, 
I'm trying to get some coordinates which come from the search results automatically into a form. Is there an easy way of doing this?

This is my form that I want it to appear on.
<form action="getSavedLocation()" method="get">
  Latitude: <input type="text" name="saved_lat"><br>
  Longitude: <input type="text" name="saved_lon"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: You need to make use of `cURL` to post the data to another form. That is a completely different topic as it cannot be covered here. It's better if you open an another question regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: Oh right thanks. Just another couple of follow up quesiton regarding the previous question. If I click on search without entering any information it still displays all the information in the table. Any way of preventing this? Also I would like for two coloumns to be be the search criteria. How can I add the other coloumn name to the code?

Comment: I get this error. .Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search.php on line 99

When I change it to an or ( " || " ) I get the previous error which I showed to you. Any suggestions? Sorry for the repeated questions.

Comment: Sorry but this code doesn't seem to work. I think its because searchekeyword is defined in the parentheses? i get this error

The search criteria cannot be empty !
Notice: Undefined variable: searchKeyword in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search.php on line 113

Notice: Undefined variable: searchKeyword2 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search.php on line 113

It displays all the information again in the table
Sorry again!